# Transform Data Structure in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I'm working with R and my dataset looks like this :

| Day | Test1 | Test2 | Test 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | NA | 30 |
| 2 | NA | 12 | 35 |

- Code for the input `dataframe`:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Day = c(1,2),
                  Test1 = c(25,NA),
                  Test2 = c(NA,12),
                  Test3 = c(30, 35))
```

is there a way to change it to this structure :

| Day | Test | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 25 |
| 1 | Test2 | NA |
| 1 | Test3 | 30 |
| 2 | Test1 | NA |
| 2 | Test2 | 12 |
| 2 | Test3 | 35 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 pivot_longer(-Day, names_to = "Test", values_to = "Values")
```